# how can I plot actual, fitted and residuals

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, economics

i would like to know if i can plot actual, fittedvalues and residuals like in eviews but in R. I've tried xyplot but doesn't look the same. 
i used this code:
xyplot(actual+residuals+fittedvalues ~ time)

Comment: I can see it is difficult for you to show us what you want, but you need the post the xyplot code you refer to as well as a sample data set to work with.

Comment: i just added the code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the eviews charts look like, but when I want to see actual, fitted and residuals, I usually use a workflow like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(y = rnorm(1000),
       x1 = y + rnorm(1000, 1, 10),
       x2 = y + rnorm(1000, 10, 1))

model <- lm(y ~ ., data)

model %>% 
  predict() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rename(.pred = value) %>% 
  bind_cols(data %>% 
              select(y)) %>% 
  mutate(.resid = y - .pred) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = y, y = .pred, color = .resid)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) +
  labs(x = "Actual",
       y = "Fitted",
       color = "Residuals")
```

[actual v fitted w residuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eql6W.png)